# Is there a CSS equivalent of XAML's * unit?

Tags: xaml, css

In XAML, you can define a size property (such a length or width) in "*" units, in which * represents a part of the remaining space.

So, if I have a parent element that is 1000px wide, and it has 2 children, which are both defined as being 1* wide, they will be 500px each. If one is defined as 3*, and the other as 1*, then one will be 750px, the other 250px.
If there is a third element, and the widths of the 3 are defined as "100px", "*" "2*" respectively, then the widths of the 3 will be 100px, 300px, 600px.

Is there a CSS equivalent of this, or should I just simulate it using calc()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flexible box layout model](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/flexbox/quick/) does that with [an OK support matrix](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) (no IE)

It does exactly what you're after, e.g. for your scenario 3:

```
<div class="box">
  <div>un</div><div>deux</div><div>trois</div>
</div>

.box {
  width: 1000px;
  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
}

.box > div:nth-child(1){ width:100px; }
.box > div:nth-child(2){ box-flex: 1; }
.box > div:nth-child(3){ box-flex: 2; }
```

[Fiddle'd](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/pEAea/1/) from html5rocks example

Answer (score 0):

Although ratios aren't supported in CSS, percentages are. This means you can't really specify "the rest of the width", but you can normally get what you want.

For example, your first example of 1000px with 1* could be achieved by assigning `width: 50%'. Your second example would be 75% and 25%.

Your third example is a bit more complicated, mixing fixed px values and percentage values won't work. What you can do is use some clever margins to get the overall result.

I have created a [JS Fiddle to illustrate the third example](http://jsfiddle.net/9AUNx/1/).

Comment: I appreciate the effort that you put into the answer, but this is the exact sort of solution I'm trying to avoid going forward, as it really falls apart once pages and their content become dynamic.

Comment: @JordaanMylonas you realise that box-flex isn't yet supported in Internet Explorer? This may only be an issue for you if you put your page on The Web.